# All official downloads for Gracenote Entourage SDK v2.4.1.4018 are invalid/incomplete ZIP files

Tags: gracenote

All official downloads for the Gracenote Entourage SDK v2.4.1.4018 are invalid/incomplete ZIP files, and are unusable.

```
$ unzip -t gn-acr-android-2.4.1.4018.zip

Archive:  gn-acr-android-2.4.1.4018.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of gn-acr-android-2.4.1.4018.zip or
        gn-acr-android-2.4.1.4018.zip.zip, and cannot find gn-acr-android-2.4.1.4018.zip.ZIP, period.
```

This means all the downloads posted at the official download page (https://developer.gracenote.com/entourage) for Android, C/C++, iOS, and Windows Phone 8 are unusuable.

How may I access SDK's for "Android" and "C/C++" platforms?

*(for the record: Windows RT, which I'm not interested in ATM, has an older release posted—2.3.1—which is a usable zip file.)*

*Note: I've already attempted to re-download the SDK's from completely different devices, over completely independent network connections: the resulting files are the same—invalid.*

Comment: Just re-upload the files. Please try again and let me know if you're still experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @WYH Hmm... It's the same version number, right? Have you personally tried downloading it via the link that's exposed to developers (https://developer.gracenote.com/system/files/gn-acr-android-2.4.1.4018.zip)? Did it result in a working zip file? I'm just asking to figure out what's happening. I tried downloading again right now and received the same unusable files. They have the same hash as before. (In the case of Android, that means a 2.86 MiB file w/ an MD5 hash of BE7CD6277633AA267BC14B4C6E0ECF83; for C++, it's a 38 MiB file with an MD5 hash of 5F9451D7364B3007186C67C8487FDE08.)

Comment: you're right, they are incomplete. I've upload those files again and tested okay. Should work this time. Let me know if otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For anyone else who was trying to acquire the Entourage SDK within the last month:*

It took a while, but the files uploaded a month ago were finally confirmed by Gracenote as invalid. [They have now uploaded new, working zip files.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34626213/all-official-downloads-for-gracenote-entourage-sdk-v2-4-1-4018-are-invalid-incom?noredirect=1#comment57342713_34626213) Just download the SDK again.

@WYH Thanks Wai-Yu! I've re-downloaded the Android and C/C++ SDK's, and they both at least can be successfully unzipped now. I'll let you know if anything else comes up.